# IPOPT solver cannot solve MPC problem in presence of non-convex objective

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am using the IPOPT solver to solve a multi-agent MPC problem. I notice that once I add quadratic collision avoidance cost  `- 100 * (||xi - xj||-radius)**2`, where `radius` is a positive constant that defines my threshold distance. But after a long time the solver is stuck in a local infeasibility. I have isolated the infeasibility issue to this non-convex term because once I remove it, the solver returns an optimal solution very quickly. I wonder how I should tackle this issue? Is this type of non-convex cost simply not supported??

Below is a snippet of the verbose message returned by IPOPT:

````
******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

   1  2.0286094e+04 1.39e+00 2.24e+01  -1.0 6.71e+00    -  3.09e-01 4.43e-01f  1This is Ipopt version 3.14.11, running with linear solver MUMPS 5.4.1.

   1  2.0286094e+04 1.39e+00 2.24e+01  -1.0 6.71e+00    -  3.09e-01 4.43e-01f  1

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:    10098
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:      360
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:     1278

   2 -2.9749413e+01 4.44e-16 1.97e+00  -1.0 1.58e+00    -  6.79e-01 1.00e+00f  1   2 -2.9749413e+01 4.44e-16 1.97e+00  -1.0 1.58e+00    -  6.79e-01 1.00e+00f  1

Total number of variables............................:      558
   3 -2.9765454e+03 4.44e-16 6.44e+00  -1.0 3.84e+00    -  4.81e-01 5.27e-01f  1   3 -2.9765454e+03 4.44e-16 6.44e+00  -1.0 3.84e+00    -  4.81e-01 5.27e-01f  1                     variables with only lower bounds:        0


                variables with lower and upper bounds:        0
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:      378
Total number of inequality constraints...............:      360
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:      180
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:      180

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   4 -3.1661760e+03 8.88e-16 1.72e-01  -1.0 1.72e-01   0.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1   0  5.4225816e+04 2.50e+00 4.45e+00  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0   4 -3.1661760e+03 8.88e-16 1.72e-01  -1.0 1.72e-01   0.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1


   5 -3.9198387e+03 4.44e-16 3.36e-01  -2.5 4.57e-01  -0.5 9.39e-01 9.81e-01f  1   1  2.0286094e+04 1.39e+00 2.24e+01  -1.0 6.71e+00    -  3.09e-01 4.43e-01f  1

   5 -3.9198387e+03 4.44e-16 3.36e-01  -2.5 4.57e-01  -0.5 9.39e-01 9.81e-01f  1   2 -2.9749413e+01 4.44e-16 1.97e+00  -1.0 1.58e+00    -  6.79e-01 1.00e+00f  1

   6 -4.9801952e+03 6.66e-16 3.81e-01  -2.5 2.65e+00  -1.0 9.15e-01 3.88e-01f  1   3 -2.9765454e+03 4.44e-16 6.44e+00  -1.0 3.84e+00    -  4.81e-01 5.27e-01f  1
   6 -4.9801952e+03 6.66e-16 3.81e-01  -2.5 2.65e+00  -1.0 9.15e-01 3.88e-01f  1

   7 -5.3220466e+03 4.44e-16 2.87e-01  -2.5 9.99e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 3.19e-01f  1
   7 -5.3220466e+03 4.44e-16 2.87e-01  -2.5 9.99e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 3.19e-01f  1   4 -3.1661760e+03 8.88e-16 1.72e-01  -1.0 1.72e-01   0.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1

   8 -5.6214071e+03 8.88e-16 7.98e-01  -2.5 1.18e+01  -1.0 4.64e-01 2.45e-02f  1   8 -5.6214071e+03 8.88e-16 7.98e-01  -2.5 1.18e+01  -1.0 4.64e-01 2.45e-02f  1   5 -3.9198387e+03 4.44e-16 3.36e-01  -2.5 4.57e-01  -0.5 9.39e-01 9.81e-01f  1


   6 -4.9801952e+03 6.66e-16 3.81e-01  -2.5 2.65e+00  -1.0 9.15e-01 3.88e-01f  1   9 -6.1364327e+03 4.44e-16 7.32e-01  -2.5 1.13e+00  -0.6 1.00e+00 3.73e-01f  1

   9 -6.1364327e+03 4.44e-16 7.32e-01  -2.5 1.13e+00  -0.6 1.00e+00 3.73e-01f  1iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  10 -6.5974272e+03 6.66e-16 2.61e+00  -2.5 8.11e+00  -1.1 6.30e-01 5.25e-02f  1
   7 -5.3220466e+03 4.44e-16 2.87e-01  -2.5 9.99e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 3.19e-01f  1

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   8 -5.6214071e+03 8.88e-16 7.98e-01  -2.5 1.18e+01  -1.0 4.64e-01 2.45e-02f  1
  10 -6.5974272e+03 6.66e-16 2.61e+00  -2.5 8.11e+00  -1.1 6.30e-01 5.25e-02f  1  11 -7.1050386e+03 4.44e-16 8.68e-01  -2.5 1.30e+00  -0.6 1.00e+00 3.17e-01f  1

  11 -7.1050386e+03 4.44e-16 8.68e-01  -2.5 1.30e+00  -0.6 1.00e+00 3.17e-01f  1   9 -6.1364327e+03 4.44e-16 7.32e-01  -2.5 1.13e+00  -0.6 1.00e+00 3.73e-01f  1  12 -7.7308218e+03 8.88e-16 2.39e+00  -2.5 6.70e+00  -1.1 7.78e-01 9.61e-02f  1


iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  12 -7.7308218e+03 8.88e-16 2.39e+00  -2.5 6.70e+00  -1.1 7.78e-01 9.61e-02f  1  10 -6.5974272e+03 6.66e-16 2.61e+00  -2.5 8.11e+00  -1.1 6.30e-01 5.25e-02f  1

  13 -8.3857683e+03 4.44e-16 6.40e-01  -2.5 1.38e+00  -0.7 1.00e+00 4.61e-01f  1
  11 -7.1050386e+03 4.44e-16 8.68e-01  -2.5 1.30e+00  -0.6 1.00e+00 3.17e-01f  1  13 -8.3857683e+03 4.44e-16 6.40e-01  -2.5 1.38e+00  -0.7 1.00e+00 4.61e-01f  1
  14 -8.6583553e+03 8.88e-16 2.35e-01  -2.5 4.55e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 5.39e-01f  1

  12 -7.7308218e+03 8.88e-16 2.39e+00  -2.5 6.70e+00  -1.1 7.78e-01 9.61e-02f  1
  15 -8.8565001e+03 4.44e-16 6.99e-01  -2.5 1.22e+00  -0.7 1.00e+00 1.70e-01f  1
  14 -8.6583553e+03 8.88e-16 2.35e-01  -2.5 4.55e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 5.39e-01f  1
  13 -8.3857683e+03 4.44e-16 6.40e-01  -2.5 1.38e+00  -0.7 1.00e+00 4.61e-01f  1
  16 -9.0512437e+03 8.88e-16 2.78e-01  -2.5 4.02e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 4.79e-01f  1
  15 -8.8565001e+03 4.44e-16 6.99e-01  -2.5 1.22e+00  -0.7 1.00e+00 1.70e-01f  1
  14 -8.6583553e+03 8.88e-16 2.35e-01  -2.5 4.55e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 5.39e-01f  1
  17 -9.3150057e+03 8.88e-16 4.40e-01  -2.5 1.26e+00  -0.8 1.00e+00 2.24e-01f  1  16 -9.0512437e+03 8.88e-16 2.78e-01  -2.5 4.02e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 4.79e-01f  1

  17 -9.3150057e+03 8.88e-16 4.40e-01  -2.5 1.26e+00  -0.8 1.00e+00 2.24e-01f  1  15 -8.8565001e+03 4.44e-16 6.99e-01  -2.5 1.22e+00  -0.7 1.00e+00 1.70e-01f  1

  18 -9.4113959e+03 4.44e-16 3.64e-01  -2.5 4.39e-01  -0.4 1.00e+00 2.50e-01f  1
  19 -9.7311671e+03 4.44e-16 3.24e-01  -2.5 1.29e+00  -0.8 1.00e+00 2.89e-01f  1  16 -9.0512437e+03 8.88e-16 2.78e-01  -2.5 4.02e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 4.79e-01f  1

  18 -9.4113959e+03 4.44e-16 3.64e-01  -2.5 4.39e-01  -0.4 1.00e+00 2.50e-01f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  20 -9.7928735e+03 8.88e-16 2.30e-01  -2.5 3.96e-01  -0.4 1.00e+00 1.67e-01f  1  17 -9.3150057e+03 8.88e-16 4.40e-01  -2.5 1.26e+00  -0.8 1.00e+00 2.24e-01f  1

  19 -9.7311671e+03 4.44e-16 3.24e-01  -2.5 1.29e+00  -0.8 1.00e+00 2.89e-01f  1
  21 -9.9900167e+03 4.44e-16 3.77e-01  -2.5 1.01e+00  -0.9 1.00e+00 2.16e-01f  1
  18 -9.4113959e+03 4.44e-16 3.64e-01  -2.5 4.39e-01  -0.4 1.00e+00 2.50e-01f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  20 -9.7928735e+03 8.88e-16 2.30e-01  -2.5 3.96e-01  -0.4 1.00e+00 1.67e-01f  1
  22 -1.0166560e+04 4.44e-16 1.52e-01  -2.5 4.09e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 6.07e-01f  1  19 -9.7311671e+03 4.44e-16 3.24e-01  -2.5 1.29e+00  -0.8 1.00e+00 2.89e-01f  1

  21 -9.9900167e+03 4.44e-16 3.77e-01  -2.5 1.01e+00  -0.9 1.00e+00 2.16e-01f  1
  23 -1.0315450e+04 8.88e-16 2.07e-01  -2.5 1.05e+00  -0.9 1.00e+00 2.22e-01f  1iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  20 -9.7928735e+03 8.88e-16 2.30e-01  -2.5 3.96e-01  -0.4 1.00e+00 1.67e-01f  1

  22 -1.0166560e+04 4.44e-16 1.52e-01  -2.5 4.09e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 6.07e-01f  1
  24 -1.0429169e+04 8.88e-16 1.20e-01  -2.5 3.62e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 5.15e-01f  1  21 -9.9900167e+03 4.44e-16 3.77e-01  -2.5 1.01e+00  -0.9 1.00e+00 2.16e-01f  1

  23 -1.0315450e+04 8.88e-16 2.07e-01  -2.5 1.05e+00  -0.9 1.00e+00 2.22e-01f  1
  25 -1.0520658e+04 4.44e-16 1.48e-01  -2.5 9.03e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.84e-01f  1  22 -1.0166560e+04 4.44e-16 1.52e-01  -2.5 4.09e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 6.07e-01f  1

  24 -1.0429169e+04 8.88e-16 1.20e-01  -2.5 3.62e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 5.15e-01f  1
  23 -1.0315450e+04 8.88e-16 2.07e-01  -2.5 1.05e+00  -0.9 1.00e+00 2.22e-01f  1  26 -1.0681889e+04 4.44e-16 9.45e-02  -2.5 3.45e-01  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1

  25 -1.0520658e+04 4.44e-16 1.48e-01  -2.5 9.03e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.84e-01f  1  27 -1.0740553e+04 4.44e-16 1.88e-01  -2.5 9.02e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.65e-01f  1  24 -1.0429169e+04 8.88e-16 1.20e-01  -2.5 3.62e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 5.15e-01f  1


  25 -1.0520658e+04 4.44e-16 1.48e-01  -2.5 9.03e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.84e-01f  1  26 -1.0681889e+04 4.44e-16 9.45e-02  -2.5 3.45e-01  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1

  28 -1.0805513e+04 4.44e-16 8.25e-02  -2.5 3.17e-01  -0.6 1.00e+00 5.52e-01f  1
  26 -1.0681889e+04 4.44e-16 9.45e-02  -2.5 3.45e-01  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1  27 -1.0740553e+04 4.44e-16 1.88e-01  -2.5 9.02e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.65e-01f  1

  29 -1.0917673e+04 4.44e-16 2.40e-01  -2.5 1.31e+00  -1.1 1.00e+00 3.17e-01f  1
  27 -1.0740553e+04 4.44e-16 1.88e-01  -2.5 9.02e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.65e-01f  1
  28 -1.0805513e+04 4.44e-16 8.25e-02  -2.5 3.17e-01  -0.6 1.00e+00 5.52e-01f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  30 -1.0979921e+04 4.44e-16 9.09e-02  -2.5 4.10e-01  -0.7 1.00e+00 5.47e-01f  1
  28 -1.0805513e+04 4.44e-16 8.25e-02  -2.5 3.17e-01  -0.6 1.00e+00 5.52e-01f  1  29 -1.0917673e+04 4.44e-16 2.40e-01  -2.5 1.31e+00  -1.1 1.00e+00 3.17e-01f  1

  31 -1.1013635e+04 4.44e-16 8.67e-02  -2.5 1.51e-01  -0.2 1.00e+00 8.47e-01f  1
  29 -1.0917673e+04 4.44e-16 2.40e-01  -2.5 1.31e+00  -1.1 1.00e+00 3.17e-01f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  32 -1.1155013e+04 8.88e-16 1.04e-01  -2.5 5.42e-01  -0.7 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  30 -1.0979921e+04 4.44e-16 9.09e-02  -2.5 4.10e-01  -0.7 1.00e+00 5.47e-01f  1iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls

  30 -1.0979921e+04 4.44e-16 9.09e-02  -2.5 4.10e-01  -0.7 1.00e+00 5.47e-01f  1  33 -1.1195171e+04 8.88e-16 1.05e-01  -2.5 2.05e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 6.82e-01f  1

  31 -1.1013635e+04 4.44e-16 8.67e-02  -2.5 1.51e-01  -0.2 1.00e+00 8.47e-01f  1
  31 -1.1013635e+04 4.44e-16 8.67e-02  -2.5 1.51e-01  -0.2 1.00e+00 8.47e-01f  1
  32 -1.1155013e+04 8.88e-16 1.04e-01  -2.5 5.42e-01  -0.7 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  32 -1.1155013e+04 8.88e-16 1.04e-01  -2.5 5.42e-01  -0.7 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  33 -1.1195171e+04 8.88e-16 1.05e-01  -2.5 2.05e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 6.82e-01f  1
  33 -1.1195171e+04 8.88e-16 1.05e-01  -2.5 2.05e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 6.82e-01f  1
  34 -1.1305674e+04 8.88e-16 1.31e-01  -2.5 6.80e-01  -0.8 1.00e+00 6.98e-01f  1
  34 -1.1305674e+04 8.88e-16 1.31e-01  -2.5 6.80e-01  -0.8 1.00e+00 6.98e-01f  1
  35 -1.1357983e+04 4.44e-16 1.09e-01  -2.5 2.40e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 8.09e-01f  1
  35 -1.1357983e+04 4.44e-16 1.09e-01  -2.5 2.40e-01  -0.3 1.00e+00 8.09e-01f  1
  36 -1.1495264e+04 4.44e-16 1.11e-01  -2.5 7.65e-01  -0.8 1.00e+00 8.22e-01f  1
  36 -1.1495264e+04 4.44e-16 1.11e-01  -2.5 7.65e-01  -0.8 1.00e+00 8.22e-01f  1
  37 -1.1541640e+04 8.88e-16 1.10e-01  -2.5 2.71e-01  -0.4 1.00e+00 6.66e-01f  1  37 -1.1541640e+04 8.88e-16 1.10e-01  -2.5 2.71e-01  -0.4 1.00e+00 6.66e-01f  1

  38 -1.1625748e+04 4.44e-16 1.96e-01  -2.5 8.06e-01  -0.9 1.00e+00 5.24e-01f  1  38 -1.1625748e+04 4.44e-16 1.96e-01  -2.5 8.06e-01  -0.9 1.00e+00 5.24e-01f  1

  39 -1.1649056e+04 4.44e-16 1.47e-01  -2.5 2.59e-01  -0.4 1.00e+00 4.51e-01f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  40 -1.1692578e+04 8.88e-16 9.82e-02  -2.5 7.46e-01  -0.9 1.00e+00 3.17e-01f  1
  39 -1.1649056e+04 4.44e-16 1.47e-01  -2.5 2.59e-01  -0.4 1.00e+00 4.51e-01f  1
  41 -1.1724686e+04 4.44e-16 8.02e-02  -2.5 2.42e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 8.36e-01f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  40 -1.1692578e+04 8.88e-16 9.82e-02  -2.5 7.46e-01  -0.9 1.00e+00 3.17e-01f  1  42 -1.1747588e+04 4.44e-16 1.31e-01  -2.5 5.81e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 3.16e-01f  1

  41 -1.1724686e+04 4.44e-16 8.02e-02  -2.5 2.42e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 8.36e-01f  1  43 -1.1764889e+04 8.88e-16 5.93e-02  -2.5 2.09e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 7.52e-01f  1

  44 -1.1812795e+04 8.88e-16 4.96e-02  -2.5 5.23e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1  42 -1.1747588e+04 4.44e-16 1.31e-01  -2.5 5.81e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 3.16e-01f  1

  45 -1.1825875e+04 4.44e-16 4.63e-02  -2.5 1.80e-01  -0.6 1.00e+00 8.12e-01f  1  43 -1.1764889e+04 8.88e-16 5.93e-02  -2.5 2.09e-01  -0.5 1.00e+00 7.52e-01f  1

  46 -1.1841179e+04 4.44e-16 5.32e-02  -2.5 3.67e-01  -1.1 1.00e+00 5.05e-01f  1
  44 -1.1812795e+04 8.88e-16 4.96e-02  -2.5 5.23e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  47 -1.1847163e+04 4.44e-16 3.00e-02  -2.5 1.10e-01  -0.6 1.00e+00 8.76e-01f  1
  45 -1.1825875e+04 4.44e-16 4.63e-02  -2.5 1.80e-01  -0.6 1.00e+00 8.12e-01f  1
  48 -1.1849096e+04 8.88e-16 2.61e-02  -2.5 4.35e-02  -0.2 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  46 -1.1841179e+04 4.44e-16 5.32e-02  -2.5 3.67e-01  -1.1 1.00e+00 5.05e-01f  1
  49 -1.1887148e+04 4.44e-16 2.56e-02  -3.8 1.28e-01  -0.7 1.00e+00 9.88e-01f  1
  47 -1.1847163e+04 4.44e-16 3.00e-02  -2.5 1.10e-01  -0.6 1.00e+00 8.76e-01f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  50 -1.1890817e+04 8.88e-16 2.46e-02  -3.8 4.61e-02  -0.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  48 -1.1849096e+04 8.88e-16 2.61e-02  -2.5 4.35e-02  -0.2 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  51 -1.1894292e+04 4.44e-16 2.31e-02  -3.8 1.25e-01  -0.8 1.00e+00 5.90e-01f  1
  49 -1.1887148e+04 4.44e-16 2.56e-02  -3.8 1.28e-01  -0.7 1.00e+00 9.88e-01f  1
  52 -1.1896319e+04 4.44e-16 2.22e-02  -3.8 4.68e-02  -0.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  50 -1.1890817e+04 8.88e-16 2.46e-02  -3.8 4.61e-02  -0.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  53 -1.1900925e+04 4.44e-16 1.99e-02  -3.8 1.24e-01  -0.8 1.00e+00 8.80e-01f  1
  51 -1.1894292e+04 4.44e-16 2.31e-02  -3.8 1.25e-01  -0.8 1.00e+00 5.90e-01f  1
  54 -1.1901443e+04 8.88e-16 3.75e-02  -3.8 4.33e-02  -0.4 1.00e+00 3.49e-01f  1
  52 -1.1896319e+04 4.44e-16 2.22e-02  -3.8 4.68e-02  -0.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1  55 -1.1902957e+04 4.44e-16 2.40e-02  -3.8 1.21e-01  -0.9 1.00e+00 4.65e-01f  1

  53 -1.1900925e+04 4.44e-16 1.99e-02  -3.8 1.24e-01  -0.8 1.00e+00 8.80e-01f  1
  56 -1.1904085e+04 8.88e-16 1.72e-02  -3.8 4.59e-02  -0.4 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  57 -1.1906850e+04 8.88e-16 1.57e-02  -3.8 1.26e-01  -0.9 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  54 -1.1901443e+04 8.88e-16 3.75e-02  -3.8 4.33e-02  -0.4 1.00e+00 3.49e-01f  1
  58 -1.1907718e+04 8.88e-16 1.51e-02  -3.8 4.53e-02  -0.5 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  55 -1.1902957e+04 4.44e-16 2.40e-02  -3.8 1.21e-01  -0.9 1.00e+00 4.65e-01f  1
  59 -1.1909719e+04 4.44e-16 1.34e-02  -3.8 1.21e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  56 -1.1904085e+04 8.88e-16 1.72e-02  -3.8 4.59e-02  -0.4 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  60 -1.1910379e+04 4.44e-16 1.28e-02  -3.8 4.31e-02  -0.5 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  57 -1.1906850e+04 8.88e-16 1.57e-02  -3.8 1.26e-01  -0.9 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  61 -1.1911916e+04 4.44e-16 1.11e-02  -3.8 1.13e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  58 -1.1907718e+04 8.88e-16 1.51e-02  -3.8 4.53e-02  -0.5 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  62 -1.1912385e+04 4.44e-16 1.05e-02  -3.8 3.99e-02  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  59 -1.1909719e+04 4.44e-16 1.34e-02  -3.8 1.21e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  63 -1.1913218e+04 4.44e-16 9.18e-03  -3.8 1.00e-01  -1.1 1.00e+00 7.69e-01f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  60 -1.1910379e+04 4.44e-16 1.28e-02  -3.8 4.31e-02  -0.5 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  64 -1.1913350e+04 4.44e-16 8.79e-03  -3.8 3.76e-02  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  61 -1.1911916e+04 4.44e-16 1.11e-02  -3.8 1.13e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  65 -1.1913467e+04 8.88e-16 8.05e-03  -3.8 1.29e-02  -0.2 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  62 -1.1912385e+04 4.44e-16 1.05e-02  -3.8 3.99e-02  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  66 -1.1913758e+04 4.44e-16 7.22e-03  -3.8 3.48e-02  -0.7 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  63 -1.1913218e+04 4.44e-16 9.18e-03  -3.8 1.00e-01  -1.1 1.00e+00 7.69e-01f  1
  67 -1.1913840e+04 4.44e-16 7.15e-03  -3.8 1.29e-02  -0.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  64 -1.1913350e+04 4.44e-16 8.79e-03  -3.8 3.76e-02  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  68 -1.1914039e+04 8.88e-16 6.69e-03  -3.8 3.63e-02  -0.7 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  65 -1.1913467e+04 8.88e-16 8.05e-03  -3.8 1.29e-02  -0.2 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  69 -1.1914106e+04 4.44e-16 6.49e-03  -3.8 1.32e-02  -0.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  66 -1.1913758e+04 4.44e-16 7.22e-03  -3.8 3.48e-02  -0.7 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  70 -1.1914276e+04 8.88e-16 5.89e-03  -3.8 3.59e-02  -0.8 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  67 -1.1913840e+04 4.44e-16 7.15e-03  -3.8 1.29e-02  -0.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  71 -1.1914333e+04 4.44e-16 5.66e-03  -3.8 1.29e-02  -0.4 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  68 -1.1914039e+04 8.88e-16 6.69e-03  -3.8 3.63e-02  -0.7 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1  72 -1.1914476e+04 4.44e-16 5.04e-03  -3.8 3.45e-02  -0.8 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1

  73 -1.1914524e+04 4.44e-16 4.78e-03  -3.8 1.23e-02  -0.4 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1  69 -1.1914106e+04 4.44e-16 6.49e-03  -3.8 1.32e-02  -0.3 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1

  74 -1.1914648e+04 8.88e-16 4.15e-03  -3.8 3.20e-02  -0.9 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  70 -1.1914276e+04 8.88e-16 5.89e-03  -3.8 3.59e-02  -0.8 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  75 -1.1914692e+04 8.88e-16 3.84e-03  -3.8 1.11e-02  -0.5 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  71 -1.1914333e+04 4.44e-16 5.66e-03  -3.8 1.29e-02  -0.4 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  76 -1.1914895e+04 4.44e-16 3.11e-03  -3.8 2.70e-02  -0.9 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  72 -1.1914476e+04 4.44e-16 5.04e-03  -3.8 3.45e-02  -0.8 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  77 -1.1915024e+04 4.44e-16 3.40e-03  -3.8 1.10e-02  -0.5 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  73 -1.1914524e+04 4.44e-16 4.78e-03  -3.8 1.23e-02  -0.4 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  78 -1.1919159e+04 8.88e-16 1.51e-02  -3.8 1.48e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  74 -1.1914648e+04 8.88e-16 4.15e-03  -3.8 3.20e-02  -0.9 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  79 -1.1923387e+04 8.88e-16 2.13e-02  -3.8 7.81e-02  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  75 -1.1914692e+04 8.88e-16 3.84e-03  -3.8 1.11e-02  -0.5 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  80 -1.2408366e+04 4.44e-16 1.62e-01  -3.8 1.78e+00  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  76 -1.1914895e+04 4.44e-16 3.11e-03  -3.8 2.70e-02  -0.9 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  81 -1.3029263e+04 4.44e-16 2.49e-01  -3.8 1.03e+00  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  77 -1.1915024e+04 4.44e-16 3.40e-03  -3.8 1.10e-02  -0.5 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  82 -1.3154451e+04 4.44e-16 2.64e-01  -3.8 4.46e-01  -0.2 1.00e+00 3.74e-01f  1
  78 -1.1919159e+04 8.88e-16 1.51e-02  -3.8 1.48e-01  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  83 -1.3582239e+04 4.44e-16 8.27e-01  -3.8 1.71e+00  -0.7 1.00e+00 3.35e-01f  1
  79 -1.1923387e+04 8.88e-16 2.13e-02  -3.8 7.81e-02  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1  84 -1.3585795e+04 4.44e-16 2.22e+00  -3.8 2.01e+01  -1.1 2.24e-01 2.40e-04f  1

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  85 -1.4139380e+04 8.88e-16 8.37e-01  -3.8 1.99e+00  -0.7 1.00e+00 3.45e-01f  1
  80 -1.2408366e+04 4.44e-16 1.62e-01  -3.8 1.78e+00  -1.0 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  86 -1.4163637e+04 8.88e-16 2.41e+00  -3.8 1.71e+01  -1.2 2.99e-01 1.84e-03f  1
  81 -1.3029263e+04 4.44e-16 2.49e-01  -3.8 1.03e+00  -0.6 1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
  87 -1.4754593e+04 8.88e-16 9.25e-01  -3.8 2.26e+00  -0.8 1.00e+00 3.11e-01f  1
  82 -1.3154451e+04 4.44e-16 2.64e-01  -3.8 4.46e-01  -0.2 1.00e+00 3.74e-01f  1
  88 -1.4876592e+04 8.88e-16 2.29e+00  -3.8 1.04e+01  -1.2 4.29e-01 1.19e-02f  1
  83 -1.3582239e+04 4.44e-16 8.27e-01  -3.8 1.71e+00  -0.7 1.00e+00 3.35e-01f  1
  89 -1.5246090e+04 8.88e-16 7.58e-01  -3.8 1.88e+00  -0.8 1.00e+00 2.53e-01f  1  84 -1.3585795e+04 4.44e-16 2.22e+00  -3.8 2.01e+01  -1.1 2.24e-01 2.40e-04f  1

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  90 -1.5555497e+04 8.88e-16 1.66e+00  -3.8 7.10e+00  -1.3 7.33e-01 5.65e-02f  1  85 -1.4139380e+04 8.88e-16 8.37e-01  -3.8 1.99e+00  -0.7 1.00e+00 3.45e-01f  1

  86 -1.4163637e+04 8.88e-16 2.41e+00  -3.8 1.71e+01  -1.2 2.99e-01 1.84e-03f  1  91 -1.5710439e+04 8.88e-16 6.09e-01  -3.8 1.31e+00  -0.9 1.00e+00 1.25e-01f  1

  92 -1.6122865e+04 8.88e-16 1.25e+00  -3.8 4.53e+00  -1.3 1.00e+00 1.24e-01f  1  87 -1.4754593e+04 8.88e-16 9.25e-01  -3.8 2.26e+00  -0.8 1.00e+00 3.11e-01f  1

  88 -1.4876592e+04 8.88e-16 2.29e+00  -3.8 1.04e+01  -1.2 4.29e-01 1.19e-02f  1
  93 -1.6281605e+04 8.88e-16 4.63e-01  -3.8 1.38e+00  -0.9 1.00e+00 1.58e-01f  1
  94 -1.6454487e+04 8.88e-16 8.61e-01  -3.8 3.86e+00  -1.4 1.00e+00 7.01e-02f  1  89 -1.5246090e+04 8.88e-16 7.58e-01  -3.8 1.88e+00  -0.8 1.00e+00 2.53e-01f  1

  95 -1.6709991e+04 1.33e-15 1.50e+00  -3.8 9.25e+00  -1.9 1.00e+00 6.14e-02f  1iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls

  90 -1.5555497e+04 8.88e-16 1.66e+00  -3.8 7.10e+00  -1.3 7.33e-01 5.65e-02f  1
  96 -1.6928904e+04 1.33e-15 1.34e+00  -3.8 1.10e+01    -  5.63e-01 6.02e-02f  1
  91 -1.5710439e+04 8.88e-16 6.09e-01  -3.8 1.31e+00  -0.9 1.00e+00 1.25e-01f  1
  97 -1.7044094e+04 1.33e-15 5.56e-01  -3.8 5.63e+00    -  1.00e+00 8.24e-02f  1
  92 -1.6122865e+04 8.88e-16 1.25e+00  -3.8 4.53e+00  -1.3 1.00e+00 1.24e-01f  1  98 -1.7147587e+04 8.88e-16 2.46e-01  -3.8 3.06e+00    -  1.00e+00 2.23e-01f  1

  99 -1.7189306e+04 8.88e-16 1.85e-01  -3.8 2.04e+00    -  1.00e+00 1.91e-01f  1
  93 -1.6281605e+04 8.88e-16 4.63e-01  -3.8 1.38e+00  -0.9 1.00e+00 1.58e-01f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
 100 -1.7210674e+04 8.88e-16 1.77e-01  -3.8 1.46e+00    -  1.00e+00 2.15e-01f  1
  94 -1.6454487e+04 8.88e-16 8.61e-01  -3.8 3.86e+00  -1.4 1.00e+00 7.01e-02f  1
 101 -1.7225815e+04 8.88e-16 1.20e-01  -3.8 8.91e-01    -  1.00e+00 3.02e-01f  1
  95 -1.6709991e+04 1.33e-15 1.50e+00  -3.8 9.25e+00  -1.9 1.00e+00 6.14e-02f  1 102 -1.7239017e+04 4.44e-16 5.40e-02  -3.8 3.70e-01    -  1.00e+00 5.34e-01f  1

 103 -1.7245856e+04 4.44e-16 1.81e-02  -3.8 9.58e-02    -  1.00e+00 6.58e-01f  1  96 -1.6928904e+04 1.33e-15 1.34e+00  -3.8 1.10e+01    -  5.63e-01 6.02e-02f  1

 104 -1.7249326e+04 4.44e-16 1.35e-06  -3.8 1.89e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1  97 -1.7044094e+04 1.33e-15 5.56e-01  -3.8 5.63e+00    -  1.00e+00 8.24e-02f  1

 105 -1.7252311e+04 4.44e-16 5.39e-07  -5.7 1.82e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1  98 -1.7147587e+04 8.88e-16 2.46e-01  -3.8 3.06e+00    -  1.00e+00 2.23e-01f  1

 106 -1.7252317e+04 8.88e-16 7.37e-10  -5.7 7.24e-03    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1  99 -1.7189306e+04 8.88e-16 1.85e-01  -3.8 2.04e+00    -  1.00e+00 1.91e-01f  1

 107 -1.7252355e+04 4.44e-16 7.51e-11  -8.6 2.28e-03    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls

 100 -1.7210674e+04 8.88e-16 1.77e-01  -3.8 1.46e+00    -  1.00e+00 2.15e-01f  1
 108 -1.7252355e+04 8.88e-16 4.65e-13  -8.6 1.96e-04    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
 101 -1.7225815e+04 8.88e-16 1.20e-01  -3.8 8.91e-01    -  1.00e+00 3.02e-01f  1
Number of Iterations....: 108

```
````

Comment: Up to my knowledge, there is no software capable of solving non-convex problems. In such situation, only candidate solutions are obtained. The global optimization research field is still developing, and a general software like IPOPT will certainly not solve a general non-linear programming problem.

Comment: I see, but in practice, how do people really solve nonlinear MPC problems? I solved a few MPC problems by using IPOPT, and the solution actually looks very nice

Comment: I don't doubt that IPOPT can improve any given solution you have. The problem is to ensure that a point delivered by this optimization algorithm is a local minimizer. However, to answer your question, according to Wikipedia: The numerical solution of the NMPC optimal control problems is typically based on direct optimal control methods using Newton-type optimization schemes, in one of the variants: direct single shooting, direct multiple shooting methods, or direct collocation. Considering that IPOPT is a Newton-type method, you must be actually getting a good candidate for solution.